# Wpf textbox binding in tag dataTrigger failed

Tags: wpf, binding, datatrigger

Following entry does not work:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
```

I am unable to create a simple binding to the MyItems-Class within the trigger.
Outside the trigger it works.
Do I need to enter any additional binding information there?

Can someone help me?

```
   public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }

      public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems {
         get;
         set;
      }
      public ViewModel()
      {
         MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>() {
            new MyItem() { Name="1", ControlType="Button" },
            new MyItem() { Name="2", ControlType="CheckBox" },
            new MyItem() { Name="3", ControlType="TextBox" }
         };
      }
   }

   public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged {

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }

      private string name;

      public string Name {
         get { 
            return name; 
         }
         set {
            if (value != name) {
               name = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
         }
      }

      private string controlType;
      public string ControlType { get => controlType; set => controlType = value; }
   }
```

```
       <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Control Type" Binding="{Binding ControlType}"/>
                
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actual Control">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                        
                            <ContentControl>
                                <ContentControl.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ControlType}" Value="TextBox">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DataTemplate>


                                                        <TextBox Text="Test"/>
                                                        <!--   This doesn't work <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>--> 


                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </ContentControl.Style>
                            </ContentControl>
                            
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the `Content` property to the data object:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
```

Comment: @RolfPeters: Please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thanks in advance.